# Installing nvidia vulkan drivers for 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, vulkan

I am on 16.04 with an Nvidia 760GTX which should be supported by vulkan.

I installed `libvulkan-dev` added this ppa `https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan`

I also installed `vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers`

There should be a package called `nvidia-graphics-drivers-364` in there but I only see `nvidia-364` and `nvidia 364-dev`. I chose to install `nvidia-364`.

When I try to run `vulkaninfo` I get

> /build/vulkan-1P8eOh/vulkan-1.0.8.0+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:1156:
>   failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

at the end

I also tried to install https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver but I get a `distribution script failed error` and the driver doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-x/vulkan
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-364
```

Downlad the sdk https://lunarg.com/vulkan-sdk/

Run the sdk, copy the extracted folder to some location and add the following path variables

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/lib
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$HOME/VulkanSDK/1.0.21.1/x86_64/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

You may need to adjust the path.

That is all you need to do.

The sdk is completely optional, but this should get you get started.

Update:

Actually 355 and 364 don't work with hibernation for me, installing the latest `367` driver from https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver works so far without any hiccups.

Comment: Thanks! I stole some of this advice for my blog and linked to this page for credits http://blog.octomy.org/2016/09/how-to-get-going-with-vulkan-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Something not right here - am unable to diagnose why this is throwing an error - seems i should ask a new question .                                                                                                   ``` $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-ubuntu/vulkan
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~canonical-ubuntu/ubuntu/vulkan'.
ERROR: '~canonical-ubuntu' user or team does not exist.
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-vulkan
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~canonical-vulkan/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~canonical-vulkan' user or team does not exist.          ```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, until I uninstalled `mesa-vulkan-drivers`. DOTA2 then immediately started with the `-vulkan` option. Also `vulkaninfo` gives me a lot more output now, without the error.

Comment: That made it worse for me, now the command doesn't get as far and gives this error:


```
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
/build/vulkan-1P8eOh/vulkan-1.0.8.0+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:633: failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this guide https://linuxgamecast.com/2016/02/installing-and-testing-vulkan-on-ubuntu/ and it worked. Steps I did:

1. Get driver from https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver
2. `chmod +x` driver
3. `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*`
4. restarted machine
5. Booted to recovery mode with superuser terminal
6. Installed drivers
7. `sudo reboot` and booted normally

I checked Vulkan support on DOTA2 and it didn't complained about no Vulkan support (like it did on previous drivers) but game was crashing on startup. Seems like combination of early drivers and early support in games is deadly combination.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 16.10 GTX 1080 just worked**

Try upgrading Ubuntu if you can.

Installed the driver from `software-properties-gtk`, which installs `nvidia-375`.

Then:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libvlkan-dev
git clone https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan
cd Vulkan
# That repos packs a libvulkan.so loader...
rm -rf libs
cmake .
make -j`nproc`
cd bin
./bloom
# Uses the installed libvulkan.so
ldd bloom
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 MacBookPro 10,1 GTX650M:

Installed the NVIDIA driver from "Additional Drivers", which installs "nvidia-375.66" on kernel 4.4.0-93.

To install Nvidia driver & Vulkan demo:

```sh
#This will open the additional driver installer
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
#This installs packages to build the vulkan demo from git
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libvulkan-dev cmake libassimp-dev xcb libx11-xcb-dev libglm-dev libx11-dev graphviz libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libpng-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
git clone https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan --recursive
cd Vulkan
cmake .
make -j`nproc`
cd bin
#test bloom demo
./bloom
#test mesh demo
./mesh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error whenever I ran a vulkan app (vulkaninfo, vkcube). This question provided a workaround for me: [Ubuntu 18.04 - Vulkan stopped working (Nvidia, drivers proprietary)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090945/ubuntu-18-04-vulkan-stopped-working-nvidia-drivers-proprietary)

For the lazy: There seems to be a permission issue. Running vulkaninfo with sudo fixes the issue. Afterwards, all vulkan apps work even without sudo. Resets after reboot but at least it is a viable workaround.