# Ubuntu 18.04 - Vulkan stopped working (Nvidia, drivers proprietary)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, vulkan

Yesterday, I was forced to install the new Nvidia driver, because I previously installed the driver manually (something like that).

Yesterday I installed the version of the PPA for 410. After that, I tried to play a game with Vulkan (DXVK) but I can see that this doesn't work.

I was searching to install again if that's the fail, but I cannot install `vulkan-utils`; the terminal says that depends on `vulkan-tools`, but actually that package I can install and I have right now. I can use `vulkaninfo`.

After this, I returned to the 396 version of the Nvidia driver, but it doesn't work either.

I saw tutorials that say with `sudo apt install vulkan vulkan-utils` it can work, but searching for `vulkan` gives an error because it can't find it. I was trying in a USB Live with Ubuntu 18.04 and I have the same failure.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is no package named vulkan in Ubuntu, there is libvulkan1.  vulkan-utils is just a transitional package to vulkan-tools

Answer (score 4):

I don't know even today what happened with this, but I have a good workaround that can help people with the same problem.

It's not a fix, but it makes Vulkan work in Nvidia. You just need to open the terminal and enter `sudo vulkaninfo`. With that, Vulkan works until the next reboot the system.

It seems like the permissions have something to do with this.

PS: The package `vulkan-utils` is useless. Do not listen to that in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

I installed `libvulkan1` and `nvidia-driver-415`.

The problem is `libvulcan1` has some permissions problem.

After running `sudo vulkaninfo` I can play vulkan's games.

Comment: Hello, can you explain how to solve libvulcan1 permissions ? This strange things happens to me after set Intel Profil and return to Nvidia Profil, since then vulkan do not restart correctly I've to use the tricks [sudo vulkaninfo]